# Deserialize XML Node with a namespace or colon in C# MVC

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

I have the below XML as sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:api="http://www.sample.com/api">
  <entry>
    <existing>true</existing>
    <api:object category="user" id="100">
      <api:last-name>Smith</api:last-name>
      <api:first-name>John</api:first-name>
    </api:object>
  </entry>

  <entry>
    <existing>false</existing>
    <api:object category="user" id="101">
      <api:last-name>Smith</api:last-name>
      <api:first-name>Bob</api:first-name>
    </api:object>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Now I am trying to deserialize the XML and was able to successfully get the value for the node <**existing**>. The problem is I get null values for the data inside nodes with the <**api:**> prefix. I have read that this has something to do with namespaces but I could not make it work I am using C# MVC.

My models below:

**ElementsUsersRoot.cs**

```
      [Serializable]
        [XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", IsNullable = false)]

        public class ElementsUsersRoot
        {
            public ElementsUsersRoot()
            {
                ElementsUsersDetails = new List<ElementsUsersData>();
            }

            [XmlElement("entry")]

            public List<ElementsUsersData> ElementsUsersDetails { get; set; }
```

**ElementsUsersData.cs**

```
 [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("entry")]
    public class ElementsUsersData 
    {


        [XmlElement("existing")]
        public bool IsExisting { get; set; }  

        [XmlElement("api:object")]
        public ElementsUsersAttributes UserAttributes { get; set; }    

    }
```

**ElementsUsersAttributes.cs**

```
[Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("api:object", Namespace = "http://www.sample.com/api")]
    public class ElementsUsersAttributes 
{

        [XmlElement("api:first-name")]
        public string Fname { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("api:last-name")]
        public string Lname{ get; set; }
}
```

Code below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiAccount + ":" + apiPassword);
                    var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;

                    var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(apiEndpoint);
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ElementsUsersRoot));

                    ElementsUsersRoot userXmlData = (ElementsUsersRoot)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    //Add cache here
                    return userXmlData;

                }
```

Comment: Prefixes are *not* a "part" of the name. E.g. you have elements named `object` from the `http://www.sample.com/api` namespace. The fact that in *that* piece of XML, `api` was used to denote the namespace is *meaningless*.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `api` is a namespace *prefix*, it has nothing to do with the qualified name of the element.

I would also note the the `[Serializable]` attribute has nothing to do with `XmlSerializer`, so can be removed, and that the `[XmlRoot]` attribute is only relevant to the root element.

Taking all of the above into account, these classes will work:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class ElementsUsersRoot
{
    [XmlElement("entry")]
    public List<ElementsUsersData> ElementsUsersDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ElementsUsersData
{
    [XmlElement("existing")]
    public bool IsExisting { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("object", Namespace = "http://www.sample.com/api")]
    public ElementsUsersAttributes UserAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class ElementsUsersAttributes
{
    [XmlElement("first-name")]
    public string Fname { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("last-name")]
    public string Lname { get; set; }
}
```